# Chromeのデベロッパーツールでスマホ画面を見ると一部反映されていない

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

製作中のwebサイトを確認するため、Chromeのデベロッパーツールでスマホ画面を見ると一部反映されていないのですが、どうしてでしょうか？表示されないのは動画の上に配置したSNSとハンバーガーメニューのボタンです。因みにPC用の画面では表示されます。

【全文】
HTML

```
!-- ハンバーガーメニュー　丸が左上から拡大 -->
<div class="openbtn"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
<nav id="g-nav">
<div id="g-nav-list"><!--ナビの数が増えた場合縦スクロールするためのdiv※不要なら削除-->
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="circle-bg"></div>

<!----------- sns ------------>
<div class="sns">
 <div class="facebook-btn">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/akami.kodomoen?ref=py_c/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="facebook">
   <img src="img/ico-facebook-tiny.svg" alt="facebook"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="instagram-btn">
   <a href="https://www.instagram.com/akami_kodomoen/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="Instagram">
   <img src="img/ico-instagram-tiny.svg" alt="Instagram"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="youtube-btn">
   <a href="http://akamikids.blog95.fc2.com/blog-entry-7286.html/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="youtube">
   <img src="img/ico-youtube.svg" alt="youtube"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
=====ハンバーガーメニューボタン====
/*navメニュー*/
/*アクティブになったエリア*/
#g-nav.panelactive{
    /*position:fixed;にし、z-indexの数値を大きくして前面へ*/
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

/*丸の拡大*/
.circle-bg{
    position: fixed;
      z-index:800;
    /*丸の形*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #deb887;
    opacity: 0.9;
    /*丸のスタート位置と形状*/
      transform: scale(0);/*scaleをはじめは0に*/
      right:-50px;
    top:-50px;
    transition: all .6s;/*0.6秒かけてアニメーション*/
}

.circle-bg.circleactive{
    transform: scale(50);/*クラスが付与されたらscaleを拡大*/
}

/*ナビゲーションの縦スクロール*/
#g-nav-list{
    display: none;/*はじめは表示なし*/
    /*ナビの数が増えた場合縦スクロール*/
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#g-nav.panelactive #g-nav-list{
     display: block; /*クラスが付与されたら出現*/
}

/*ナビゲーション*/
#g-nav ul {
    opacity: 0;/*はじめは透過0*/
    /*ナビゲーション天地中央揃え※レイアウトによって調整してください。不必要なら削除*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

/*背景が出現後にナビゲーションを表示*/
#g-nav.panelactive ul {
    opacity:1;
}

/* 背景が出現後にナビゲーション li を表示※レイアウトによって調整してください。不必要なら削除*/
#g-nav.panelactive ul li{
animation-name:gnaviAnime;
animation-duration:1s;
animation-delay:.2s;/*0.2 秒遅らせて出現*/
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
opacity:0;
}
@keyframes gnaviAnime{
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
100% {
opacity: 1;
}
}


/*リストのレイアウト設定*/
#g-nav li{
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

#g-nav li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:10px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
#g-nav li a{
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 35px;
}
}

/*========= ボタンのためのCSS ==========*/
.openbtn{
    position: fixed;
    top:30px;
    right: 200px;
    z-index: 9999;/*ボタンを最前面に*/
    cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/*×に変化*/
.openbtn span{
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .4s;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #7fbfff;  /*元のカラー#ffa500*/
    width: 26px;
  }

.openbtn span:nth-of-type(1) {
    top:13px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.openbtn span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top:23px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.openbtn span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top:33px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.openbtn.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
    top: 17px;
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(-45deg);
    width: 36px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.openbtn.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

.openbtn.active span:nth-of-type(3){
    top: 30px;
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(45deg);
    width: 36px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}



/*---------- responsive ----------*/

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .openbtn {
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
      right: -4px;
    }
    .openbtn span {
      width: 23px;
      height: 3px;
    }
    .openbtn span:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 7.5px;
      left: 6px;
      margin-top: 9px;
    }
    .openbtn span:nth-of-type(2) {
      top: 13px;
      left: 6px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .openbtn span:nth-of-type(3) {
      top: 18.5px;
      left: 6px;
      margin-top: 11px;
    }
    .openbtn.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: 12px;
        transform: translateY(6px) rotate(-45deg);
        width: 27px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .openbtn.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .openbtn.active span:nth-of-type(3){
        top: 25px;
        transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(45deg);
        width: 27px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}


============SNSボタン=============
/*-----sns-----*/
.sns {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 30px;
  /*left: 88%;*/
  right: 25px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;   /*photoより上へ*/
  /*width: 150px;*/
}
.facebook-btn img {
  width: 30px;

}
.facebook-btn {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  /*border: solid 1px #ffffff;*/
}
.instagram-btn img {
  width: 30px;
}
.instagram-btn {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  /*border: solid 1px #ffffff;*/
}
.youtube-btn img {
  width: 30px;
}
.youtube-btn {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  /*border: solid 1px #ffffff;*/
}

/*---------- responsive ----------*/
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .sns {
    top: 90px;
    width: 30px;
    /*left: 88%;*/
    right: 25px;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 10;   /*photoより上へ*/
    /*width: 150px;*/
  }
  .facebook-btn img {
    width: 24px;

  }
  .facebook-btn {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0 ;
    padding: 6px 6px;
    /*border: solid 1px #ffffff;*/
  }
  .instagram-btn img {
    width: 24px;
  }
  .instagram-btn {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 6px 6px;
    /*border: solid 1px #ffffff;*/
  }
  .youtube-btn img {
    width: 24px;
  }
  .youtube-btn {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px ;
    padding: 6px 6px;
    /*border: solid 1px #ffffff;*/
  }
}
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
//g-nav　メニュー
$(".openbtn").click(function () {//ボタンがクリックされたら
    $(this).toggleClass('active');//ボタン自身に activeクラスを付与し
    $("#g-nav").toggleClass('panelactive');//ナビゲーションにpanelactiveクラスを付与
    $(".circle-bg").toggleClass('circleactive');//丸背景にcircleactiveクラスを付与
});

$("#g-nav a").click(function () {//ナビゲーションのリンクがクリックされたら
    $(".openbtn").removeClass('active');//ボタンの activeクラスを除去し
    $("#g-nav").removeClass('panelactive');//ナビゲーションのpanelactiveクラスを除去
    $(".circle-bg").removeClass('circleactive');//丸背景のcircleactiveクラスを除去
});
```

Comment: 問題を再現可能なソースコードを質問文へ追記していただけませんか？

Comment: コードを追加してみました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ソースコードの追記ありがとうございます。質問文のコードを実行する限りでは、ハンバーガーメニューのボタンは表示されているように見えます。こちらのリンクから動作を確認してみてくださいませんか？https://jsfiddle.net/2ro3v1yd/

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。貼っていただいたリンクから確認させていただきました。確かに表示されていますね。
そうすると動画の上（前面）に配置していることとか、またはMac上で作業しているとかが関係してるのでしょうか。

Comment: 今のところ何とも言えませんね...。問題が再現する状態のソースコードをすべて追記していただくことはできますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。全文に書き換えてみました。よろしくお願いします。因みにwindowsの検証画面でも確認しましたが同じでした。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。改めてコードを確認したのですが、依然としてハンバーガーメニューのボタンは表示されており、問題が再現していないように見えます。いかがでしょうか？https://jsfiddle.net/2ro3v1yd/1/

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確かに見えていますね。どう再現していいのか少し調べてみます。

Comment: ひとまず、「現状では問題が再現できない」および「問題を再現できるコードの追記がなされない」の二点を根拠として、質問へ「より詳細に、または明確にする必要がある」としてクローズ票を投票しました。

Comment: 了解しました。結局どう再現して良いのやら分からずそのままにしてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。クローズして結構です。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @supa  クローズしなくとも、コメントでの指摘を整理して回答にすればよいです。可能であれば再現しない理由の考察や調べ方なんかもあるとよりよいですが

Comment: @supa様　先日はいろいろとご協力いただきありがとうございました。その後、私の作っていたページでボタンの位置が表示画面からかなりはみ出した右の方に表示されていたことが分かりました。同ページの下の方で見出しで作っていた帯の背景色をレスポンシブ対応にしていなかったため、表示画面よりかなり右の方まで伸びており、そのせいで表示画面から外れて見えていたようです。おっしゃる通り表示されていました。局所的なコードしかアップしなかったので、ページ全文のコードをアップすれば見つけていただけたのかもですね。クライアントからのお仕事でしたのでプライバシーの観点から全文を送ることを避けてしまい、申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: @suzukis様　ご助言ありがとうございます。今後参考にさせていただきます。